# How does one split a page into quadrants in google docs?

Tags: google-docs

I've found a bunch of videos on how to draw a 2x2 table in Google docs.  This is not the same as splitting a page into quadrants.  There is padding around the table, and the sizes of the row ands columns are not exact.  It also doesn't scale with print size.

Is there a setting in Google Docs for quadrants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this won't scale with print size, the best I've found is to follow these steps:

1. Go to `File > Page Setup` and change all your margins to zero
2. Go to `Insert > Table` and create a 2x2 table
3. The line above your table can not be removed.  Instead, set its line height to 1.  Do the same for the line below the table.
4. Right click inside any cell and go to "Table Properties"
5. Under "column", set column width to half your sheet width (8.5/2 = 4.25)
6. Under "row", set minimum row height to have sheet height(11/2 = 5.5).  Because of the undeletable line, you may have to set the height to just a bit under half
7. Under "cell", set your cell padding as desired (I recommend .125")
8. Under "color", set you border width to zero.  If you want cut lines, set it to 0.5 and set the color to light gray, then select all outer borders and set them to zero width

This method will still require you to copy paste everything if you're trying to get multiple small pages of the same thing.